# firebase.auth().signInAnonymously() how to maintain session?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have a chat app where a non registered user can message someone who's registered. The issue is using `firebase.auth().signInAnonymously()` will generate uid and will act as a signed in user.

My concern is when the anonymous user decides to close down their browser the session between the two users will be lost.

Without requesting much/no personal information, What can I utilise in order to maintain session between a registered and non registered user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My concern is when the anonymous user decides to close down their browser the session between the two users will be lost.

Firebase stores the user's authentication state in the local storage of the browser by default, and restores it from there when the user revisits the web site. So it is not tied to their current browser session, and will survive page reloads or browser sessions.

Comment: Ah that's right so I have no more concerns. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use Firebase auth persistence, it also works with anonymous sign in.
I suggest you use LOCAL persistence level, so that the uid of the anonymous user stays the same upon browser restart, so you can keep the chat session:

```
const level = firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.LOCAL;
await firebase.auth().setPersistence(level);
```

See the documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#persistence_1